# Component not found in org after deployment from vs code

Tags: vs-code

I am facing this weird issue where after I deploy my component/class from VS Code to org, it gets successfully deployed but when I am trying to find the same component/class in my org. I cant seem to find it. Has anyone faced this issue before?

I have already deleted my previous folder and created new one and authorized my org again but still thee same issue persists.

Update:
I have noticed in my VS Code output it is saying "--json --loglevel fatal
ended with exit code 0"

Comment: It could be you have a list view, and it's filtered out. Also, is it a component, or a class? Or both?

Comment: checked its not list view... happening both with class and component

Comment: What does deployment status show in your setuo in salesforce org?

Comment: And are you sure VSCode is targeting the correct org?

Comment: yes that why i deleted the old one and created new folder and authorized the right org again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of beating, I reinstalled the vs code and salesforce cli and now it works fine.

Just to be noted in my issue, vs code was retrieving code correctly but wasn't pushing to org even though it was showing me successfully deployed message

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.  I would select **SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org**, and it would take a long time spinning before reporting back a false success message.  This was easily verified by subsequently running **SFDX: Diff File Against Org**.  The changes clearly hadn't taken hold.

To be clear, the issue seemed to impact not only the deployment of new files, but changes to existing files as well.

All I had to do to resolve it was update the Salesforce CLI by running `sfdx update` in the terminal.